# How to find IpAddress of a virtual machine programmatically from hypervisor?

Tags: powershell, wmi, vmware, powershell-2.0, hyper-v

I am using HyperV WMI provider to to update virtual machine's configuration/settings (like hard ware, disks etc..)

1. How can I get IpAddress of a VM from HyperV?
2. How to do the same thing in VMWare?

Regards,
Dreamer!

Comment: For VMWare you can have a look to PowerCli Cmdlets

Answer (score 3):

1. [This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/m2/archive/2010/07/29/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-a-virtual-machine-from-hyper-v.aspx) describes how to get the IP address of a virtual
   machine from Hyper-V (Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V) using Powershell.
2. Using the PowerCli: `(get-vm <name of your vm>).guest.ipaddress`

Answer (score 0):

For Hyper-V, this is how I usually pull an IP from a host box.

```
$vm = Get-WmiObject -computerName "." -NameSpace  "Root\Virtualization"   -query "SELECT * FROM Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent" #pulls VM WMI object ExchangeComponents
$vmitems = $vm.GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems 
$ipitem = $vmitems[-4]#yay! a hack that relies on XML schemas! 
$xmlip = [xml]$ipitem #convert string format to XML 
$ipaddr = $xmlip.INSTANCE.PROPERTY[1].VALUE #playing with XML schemas again hopefully reliably
```

It's not the neatest/cleanest/nicest code, but it is a way to get that information.

Comment: This query must be run as an Admin (at least on Windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate variation that I cooked up to demonstrate a more robust approach at finding the value for a given name.  This doesn't rely on a specific relative ordering inside the schema of Caption, Data, Description, ElementName, Name or Source

```
$vmParams = @{
  NameSpace = 'Root\Virtualization';
  Query = 'SELECT * FROM Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent' #pulls VM WMI object ExchangeComponents
}

Get-WmiObject @vmParams |
  % {
    $xml = [Xml]"<properties>$($_.GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems)</properties>"
    $xml.properties.INSTANCE.Property |
      % {
        $value = ($_.ParentNode.Property | ? { $_.Name -eq 'Data' }).VALUE
        if ($_.Value -eq 'FullyQualifiedDomainName')
        {
          Write-Host "Host: $($value)"
        }
        if ($_.Value -eq 'RDPAddressIPv4')
        {
          Write-Host "RDP Address: $($value)"
        }
      }
  }
```